# PYSPARK - How I get only value in SQLCONTEXT result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to return this Sqlcontext result in a list, but return very things and I want only value.

Pyspark CODE:

```
rdd = sqlcontext.sql('select * from Dicionario where CD_PROC="{}"'.format(processo)).rdd.map(lambda l: l).collect()
```

Result (one line):

```
[Row(CD_PROC=u'CAL-0004-LL0', NM_CAMPO=u'TIPO_REGISTRO', TIPO=u'A', TAMANHO=u'1', CD_DOMI=u'', ID_PK=u'0', DT_HOM=u'')]
```

I want:

```
[CAL-0004-LL0, TIPO_REGISTRO, A, 1, ,0,,]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Row` object is a subclass of `tuple`.

```
results = [Row(CD_PROC=u'CAL-0004-LL0', NM_CAMPO=u'TIPO_REGISTRO', TIPO=u'A', TAMANHO=u'1', CD_DOMI=u'', ID_PK=u'0', DT_HOM=u'')]
print(tuple(results[0]))  # or use list() or [:] anything you like
```

Output

```
(u'', u'CAL-0004-LL0', u'', u'0', u'TIPO_REGISTRO', u'1', u'A')
```